# Push Notifications and Storyboards

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a push notification coming into the app delegate and i want to jump to a view with in a storyboard. i've tried pushing the view controller. I've tried pushing segue and i've tried adding the view nothing works i either get nothing and stay where i am or i get a blank screen.

The storyboard is in a navigation controller.

Comment: The push notification comes into the app delegate not a view controller. How do you do the push or segue?

Comment: Yeah that's right but using the data in the push notification I need to display the news feed viewcontroller in the storyboard but how do I jump to it. I've tried several ways without success.

Comment: I know this is not much help, but you not give me much to go on. If you want to load a view in the same way that a user would load a view, then you need to simulate the user interaction that loads the view.

Comment: In most of the examples I've seen (and how I've done it before), I don't use push or segue; I present a modal view controller. This is used to display a special view that is only for push notifications.